# Close residual Selenium WebDriver instances after forced stop

Tags: java, memory-leaks, junit, selenium-webdriver, teamcity

I'd like to find some new conceptual ideas, but specific solutions are welcome.

## Technologies

- Versioning System: **SVN**
- Continuous Integration Tool: **TeamCity**
- Agent: **Windows (no admin rights!)**
- Language: **Java**
- WebDriver: **InternetExplorerDriver**
- Testing: **JUnit**
- Build: **ant**

## Problem

If someone stops a configuration (line in TeamCity GUI) while it is running, the `afterClass` method is not executed (it closes the browser) and the browser becomes residual.

## Structure

[image]

(`beforeClass` starts the driver and `afterClass` closes it)

## Flow

[image]

( where you see a red arrow, someone stops the configuration -> E.g.: (s)he observed that a test failed and wants to run it again, but it produces a residual browser because `afterClass` is not executed )

## Previous attempts

- Go to the agent and restart it manually ( 1 time / 1-4 weeks ) - works, but has important disadvantages
- Go to the agent and tried to use `taskkill` and `taskkill /F` - doesn't work
- Other Java attempts (to run a "cleaner" before the tests - native Windows commands), but without success

Do you have any ideas? They can be related to the agent, TeamCity, Java code, ant, specific configurations, etc.

Comment: Id look at junit rules TestWatcher and intercept the fail and quit driver accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, stopping of configuration is killing the jvm, leaving the browsers residual. Am I correct? If so, you could try adding shutdown hooks and handle the closing of browsers in the shutdown hook. i.e. you could put the browser closing block of code in a method and invoke that from both shutdown hook and afterClass, with proper exception handling.

I hope this answer helps you.